# laravel im making a web based reminder system that can send a message in sms

Tags: laravel, api, sms

I am making a web based reminder sysyem in laravel that can send a message in sms and I am still new to laravel could you guys help on what should I use?
I am from Philippines 
and also an sms api that can use on Philippines on the laravel 
thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use this service **[thetexting](https://thetexting.com)** . It has sample code for php or anything which you want to integrate in.
**I hope it helps.**
also you can use **[sinch](https://www.sinch.com/)** or **[twilio](http://twilio.com/)** for sms sending, search each of them.